# How to remove circled noise from image

Tags: image-processing, filtering

Consider a simplified example:

noise

```
noise = Table[
  RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[1, 0.2]] Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]^8, {x, -16, 
   16 - 16/512, 32/512}, {y, -16, 16 - 16/512, 32/512}];
```

original image

```
img1 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
```

image with noise

```
img2 = ImageAdd[img1, Image[0.2 noise]]

Row[{img1,img2}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to remove the noise and reconstruct the original image just from the noised image, assuming that the circles are all centered at the center of the image?

Comment: I would make a histogram of pixel values versus radius, which will surely reveal the periodic noise structure, then balance and project back to the original pixel space.